# Which is the best kernel version to upgrade in Debian Wheezy?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, debian-wheezy

I have Debian Wheezy kernel version 3.2.0-3-amd64 (stable).
I want to upgrade my kernel version.
[Here](https://packages.qa.debian.org/l/linux.html) there are many descriptions and source package of kernel.
I red that Torvalds has been announced the release of **Kernel 3.16 stable**, but in the link above the kernel is classify as **exprimental**. I'm bit confused.
Could anyone suggest me where's the best version if I want to upgrade the kernel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most distributions do not update to the latest kernel version available immediately. They usually have their own patchset they would apply against it for any distro-specific customization, and they need to be tested for stability with other packages in the distro before they actually enter the testing branch (Jessie), let alone the stable branch (in this case, Wheezy).

Take note that these branches are distribution specific. Torvalds' kernel tree is considered upstream from Debian, so he would announce a kernel as stable first before it trickles down to distro kernel maintainers to start integration with the Debian environment.

The best version to run is usually from the stable branch of your distribution, unless you're interested in some specific feature that is only available in a more recent version of the kernel.

Comment: So, you tell me to don't upgrade kernel?

Comment: There's no need unless you're using a specific feature/driver from it. It may not be completely stable after applying Debian's patchset to it, and it may not have the same hardware support. 3.16 will eventually work its way down the pipeline to Debian stable.  
If you're interested in running a major Linux distro as close to vanilla sources as possible, you would want to look at Slackware, Arch, or Gentoo.

Comment: and what about Bumblebee? Can I install it without any problem with my kernel and my version of Debian ?

Comment: The bumblebee package is in wheezy-backports, so you can use that. Do be aware that if you have relatively new intel card as the other half of optimus, backports does not have the updated driver. You'll have to use jessie or sid, in that case. See: https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee

Also note that you need to avoid overwriting/conflicting mesa's libgl if you're using proprietary drivers. Nouveau doesn't have this problem.